# How Convert SerializeArray to Object With Dynamic Prop Name Jquery

Tags: jquery, object, serialization, serializearray

how can convert serialized data from DOM to Object?

like :

```
const data = section.serialize();

const object = {data}
```

My current solution is:

```
const array = section.find('select, textarea, input').serializeArray();

    var myObject = {};
    $.map(array, (item, index) => {
        myObject[item.name] = item.value;
    });
```

this code convert to flat object but i hasn't any idea about inner array like:

```
obj = {
id: 1,
name : "ABC",
Persons:[] ???
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: @freedomn-m
 no, when you use serializeArray if form has "multi Select input" it return list of same name like : 
{name: 'ID', value:'888'}
{name: 'Persons', value: '11'}
{name: 'Persons', value: '12'}
{name: 'Persons', value: '13'}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, so, still, can you provide an example HTML that you want to use to generate the output that you desire?  See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To convert serialized data from the DOM to an object using jQuery, you can use the serializeArray() and then, you can convert that array into a JavaScript object using the reduce():

```js
const section = $('#yourSectionId');

const dataArray = section.find('select, textarea, input').serializeArray();

const dataObject = dataArray.reduce(function (obj, item) {
  obj[item.name] = item.value;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

A compacter way, as alternative:

```js
const section = $('#yourSectionId');

const dataObject = Object.fromEntries(section.find('select, textarea, input').serializeArray().map(({ name, value }) => [name, value]));
```